# Time in the FreeBSD jail is "jumping" every hour

Tags: time, timezone, freebsd, jail

I can't resolve my problem with time in FreeBSD JAIL :(

I have set my timezone correctly.

And I have commented this line:

```
#1,31   0-5     *       *       *       root    adjkerntz -a
```

Here is my cron log:

```
Feb  3 12:15:00 blahblah /usr/sbin/cron[87637]: (root) CMD (/usr/libexec/atrun)
Feb  3 14:15:00 blahblah /usr/sbin/cron[87662]: (root) CMD (/usr/libexec/atrun)
Feb  3 12:20:00 blahblah /usr/sbin/cron[87697]: (root) CMD (/usr/libexec/atrun)
Feb  3 14:20:00 blahblah /usr/sbin/cron[87710]: (root) CMD (/usr/libexec/atrun)
Feb  3 12:22:00 blahblah /usr/sbin/cron[87727]: (operator) CMD (/usr/libexec/save-entropy)
Feb  3 14:22:00 blahblah /usr/sbin/cron[87763]: (operator) CMD (/usr/libexec/save-entropy)
Feb  3 12:25:00 blahblah /usr/sbin/cron[87795]: (root) CMD (/usr/libexec/atrun)
Feb  3 14:25:00 blahblah /usr/sbin/cron[87799]: (root) CMD (/usr/libexec/atrun)
Feb  3 12:30:00 blahblah /usr/sbin/cron[87832]: (root) CMD (/usr/libexec/atrun)
Feb  3 14:30:00 blahblah /usr/sbin/cron[87863]: (root) CMD (/usr/libexec/atrun)
Feb  3 12:33:00 blahblah /usr/sbin/cron[87884]: (operator) CMD (/usr/libexec/save-entropy)
Feb  3 14:33:00 blahblah /usr/sbin/cron[87919]: (operator) CMD (/usr/libexec/save-entropy)
Feb  3 12:35:00 blahblah /usr/sbin/cron[87938]: (root) CMD (/usr/libexec/atrun)
Feb  3 14:35:00 blahblah /usr/sbin/cron[87948]: (root) CMD (/usr/libexec/atrun)
Feb  3 12:40:00 blahblah /usr/sbin/cron[88003]: (root) CMD (/usr/libexec/atrun)
Feb  3 14:40:00 blahblah /usr/sbin/cron[88017]: (root) CMD (/usr/libexec/atrun)
Feb  3 12:44:00 blahblah /usr/sbin/cron[88052]: (operator) CMD (/usr/libexec/save-entropy)
Feb  3 14:44:00 blahblah /usr/sbin/cron[88088]: (operator) CMD (/usr/libexec/save-entropy)
Feb  3 12:45:00 blahblah /usr/sbin/cron[88103]: (root) CMD (/usr/libexec/atrun)
Feb  3 14:45:00 blahblah /usr/sbin/cron[88128]: (root) CMD (/usr/libexec/atrun)
Feb  3 12:50:00 blahblah /usr/sbin/cron[88159]: (root) CMD (/usr/libexec/atrun)
Feb  3 14:50:00 blahblah /usr/sbin/cron[88172]: (root) CMD (/usr/libexec/atrun)
Feb  3 12:55:00 blahblah /usr/sbin/cron[88208]: (root) CMD (/usr/libexec/atrun)
Feb  3 12:55:00 blahblah /usr/sbin/cron[88207]: (operator) CMD (/usr/libexec/save-entropy)
Feb  3 14:55:00 blahblah /usr/sbin/cron[88253]: (operator) CMD (/usr/libexec/save-entropy)
Feb  3 14:55:00 blahblah /usr/sbin/cron[88254]: (root) CMD (/usr/libexec/atrun)
Feb  3 13:00:00 blahblah /usr/sbin/cron[88293]: (operator) CMD (/usr/libexec/save-entropy)
Feb  3 13:00:00 blahblah /usr/sbin/cron[88292]: (root) CMD (newsyslog)
Feb  3 13:00:00 blahblah /usr/sbin/cron[88294]: (root) CMD (/usr/libexec/atrun)
```

Comment: Resolved. My cron proccess on the host machine was running twice.

Comment: Then please close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Vladimir Resolved resolved this in the question comments.

Two cron processes were running simultaneously.